# Use eigen matrix as argument for eigen array reference

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using a library where a function takes array references and updates them:

```
void foo(ArrayXXd A&)
```

However, in my code I want to use

```
Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic>
```

How can I call the function foo with a matrix? Can I map the matrix to an array somehow?

This is the compiler error:

```
 error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Mat& {aka Eigen::Array<double, -1, -1>&}’ from expression of type ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>’
```

I did the following that seems to work, but I don't know if it is a general solution (different memory layouts and so on).

```
//X_IN is a Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic> & 

//Map Matrix to pointer
X_pntr = X_IN.data();
//Map pointer to Array 
ArrayXXd X_array = Map<ArrayXXd>(X_pntr,X_IN.rows(),X_IN.cols());

foo(X_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most objects in `Eigen` are expressions (more specifically, objects derived from `MatrixBase`). If you want to write a function that works for any type of `Matrix`/`Array` etc. and not be restricted only to e.g. `Array`, you need to write it in the following form:

```
template<typename T> 
void foo(Eigen::MatrixBase<T>& A)
{
   // do something here with A
}
```

Now you can invoke `foo` with any kind of object, for example `foo(A*A)`, where `A` is a `MatrixXd`, or `MatrixXf` or `ArrayXd`, you get the idea. See the official documentation for more details:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

After reading your comment I can just come up with this solution:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> m(2,2);
m << 1,2,3,4;
Eigen::ArrayXXd tmp = m; // convert into array (via copy)
foo(tmp); // modify tmp
m = tmp; // copy back into m
cout << m; // now m is modified
```

When `Eigen` will support move semantics, then you will be able to use `std::move` instead of making 2 copies.

Comment: I am not the author of the function, I instead want that library function to manipulate my matrix.

Comment: Ohh I see. The problem is that you are sending `A` by reference. If you send it by value then it will automatically convert the `MatrixXd` to `ArrayXXd`. However, by reference, I have no idea how to do it. There is a `Eigen::Matrix` member function called `array()`, which converts the expression to an `ArrayWrapper`, but still it cannot be passed by reference. Good question!

Comment: And the main problem is that any cast (of a non-reference type) will produce a `rvalue` which cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: A non-elegant solution is to just define `ArrayXXd tmp = your_matrix`, then invoke `foo(tmp)`, then copy back `tmp` as `your_matrix = tmp`. This will work, but it's less efficient, see the updated code.